# Transform control produces gaps in the model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm referencing the code [here](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-simple-viewer-nodejs/blob/experiment/xform-tool/public/TransformToolExtension.js) to move a model. However, I found the distance between the transfrom mesh and the object I moved, even though I used a bounding box. The larger the object, the greater the distance between the transforms.
[image]

my code

```
_onControlsChange(ev) {
    if (this.selectedModel) {
      const posTransform = this._controls.position;
      let tr = this.selectedModel.getPlacementTransform();
      tr.elements[12] = posTransform.x;
      tr.elements[13] = posTransform.y;
      tr.elements[14] = posTransform.z;
      this.selectedModel.setPlacementTransform(tr);

      this._viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);
    }
  }

_onSelectionChange(ev) {
    const selSet = ev.selections;
    const firstSel = selSet[0];

    if (firstSel) {
      const listdbIds = firstSel.dbIdArray;
      const dbidItem = listdbIds[0];
      const typeModel = dbidItem.toString().slice(0, 3);
      if (typeModel !== "500") return;

      const model = firstSel.model;
      this.selectedModel = model;
      let dbIds = firstSel.dbIdArray;
      let firstDbId = dbIds[0];
      const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
      const fragList = model.getFragmentList();
      let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
      instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(
        firstDbId,
        (fragId) => {
          let box = new THREE.Box3();
          fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, box);
          bounds.union(box);
        },
        true
      );

      const position = bounds.getCenter();
      this._controls.setPosition(position);
      this._controls.visible = true;
    } else {
      this._controls.visible = false;
      this.selectedModel = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Author of the code sample here :) It looks like the screenshot hasn't been included in your question, could you add it again? And could you please explain what your goal is? I see you've modified the original code snippet but IIRC the original code is using bounding boxes also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the screenshot. Since the beginning I used PlacementTransform to do activities like displacement, rotation. So I want to move a custom model using setPlacementTransform and TransformTool by select the model first. But I found a gap between the transform mesh and the model I want to move. In the `ControlsChange` event. I made changes by aligning the position of the Transform Control with the model I selected.

Comment: I see. So you want to move the entire _model_ instead of just the selected element. Let me look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the transform tool in the GitHub branch so that you can now configure it to move either individual objects, or entire models. See the commit https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-simple-viewer-nodejs/commit/a72ea8fa3782bf7458ff8e381f8ff578809462e7.

To configure the tool to move the entire model, initialize the extension like so:

```js
viewer.loadExtension('TransformExtension', { mode: TransformToolMode.MODEL });
```

Comment: I want ask out of topic. How to make a dropdown button like the default tool `Model Browser` provide by Autodesk Forge. Or where can I reference a class in Autodesk css?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `Model Browser` isn't using any dropdown, is it?

Comment: Sorry by that. Did you load the model ? When I open the browser model, a list of buttons will appear, which when I click it will expand to the bottom (nested button). It's like bootstrap's collapse button.

Comment: Ah I see, so not a "dropdown", but an "expandable tree". I'm afraid we don't have any example for that but it's a good suggestion for a blog post. I'll look into that :)